# No response from MIFARE CLASSIC

Tags: android, authentication, nfc

I'm trying to authenticate any sector of a MIFARE classic card. I'm using a twinlinx mymax sticker (which makes almost any bluetooth device NFC enabled). It sends commands to a connected NFC tag. I've already made a connection and sent and recieved data with a Ultralight C tag, but so far I had no success on accessing a Mifare Classic. Here is my authentication code:

```
    private boolean authenticate(int sector, byte[] key, boolean keyA) {

    byte[] cmd = new byte[12];

    // First byte is the command
    if (keyA) {
        cmd[0] = 0x60; // phHal_eMifareAuthentA
    } else {
        cmd[0] = 0x61; // phHal_eMifareAuthentB
    }

    // Second byte is block address
    cmd[1] = (byte) 0x03;

    // Next 6 bytes are the key
    System.arraycopy(key, 0, cmd, 2, 6);

    // Next 4 bytes is the UID
    System.arraycopy(Answer, 3, cmd, 8,4);

    byte[] test = null;

    //this makes a connection to the NFC tag (and this works)
    TR.ConnectToExternalCard(AUTH, (byte)0x00);

    //checking if the tag is still connected
    if (TR.isCardPresent() == true){

    //sending command to authenticate
    test = TR.SendCommandPropAndWaitResponse(cmd, (byte) 0x00);
    }

    try {
        if (test != null) {

            return true;
        }
    }
```

I'm using standard MIFARE Classic keys, the tags are fresh from the factory. The complete command (in bytes) which is sent to the tag is:

[0x60, 0x3, 0xff, 0xff, 0xff, 0xff, 0xff, 0xff, 0xf3, 0xf4, 0xa9, 0xfb]

Any Ideas? The tag seems to be non-responsive... tried accessing other Classic tags but also had no success. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

It is hard to say what you are doing wrong using an SDK that is not publicly available. However, the API looks familiar enough, so I will give it a try anyway. I can think of a number of things you may try (in decreasing order of likeliness):

1. The UID bytes may be in the wrong order, so try reversing them.
2. Perhaps `Answer` does not only contain the UID, but other bytes, too (e.g. SAK), and you are copying the wrong bytes from it.
3. The MIFARE Classic tags you have may have a 7-byte UID and you are not using the correct 4 bytes from that.
4. May be `TR.SendCommandPropAndWaitResponse()` is the wrong method to use. Perhaps there is a dedicated method for MIFARE Classic.
5. The MyMax sticker may not support MIFARE Classic. I don't see explicit confirmation on their website that they do. However, indications are that their solution is based on NXP hardware, which always supports MIFARE Classic.